# Bootstrap 3 - Problems with two menus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, responsive-design

Actually I am working with Bootstrap 3 and in my web I have two menus. When I check the responsive design  it makes me two buttons for two menus but when I click enyone it's open only the first menu. So I don't know how to do to have only one button and  both menus appear in the same div in small screen.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to post some code. We cannot help if we cannot see what is going on in the code.

Comment: Can we have code snippets of the two menus

Answer (score 0):

```html
The firstone: 

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          
        </div>
     <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
       
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right menu1">
            <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wishlist <span class="badge pull-right">(0)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Shoping cart <span class="badge pull-right">(0)</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>



the seconone:

  <div class="col-md-pull-9">
              <!-- Static navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-right menu2">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Strona Główna</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Kategorie <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Bestselery</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Biografie</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Encyklopedie</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Fantastyka</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Kuchnia i diety</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Literatura</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Nauka języków</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Nowości</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bestsellery</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Ebooki</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            </ul>
            
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
           
     </div>
```

This is my code